How to Create KPI Visuals with Custom Text, Icons, and Footer Notes in Vega-Lite
I am trying to recreate a visual of KPIs similar to the one in the attached image using Vega-Lite. As a beginner with Vega-Lite, I have written some code, but it's not working as expected. I'm facing several challenges:

Placing text exactly on the view.
Adding custom icons and colors to indicate trend changes.
Adding footer notes for baseline and updated dates.
Adjusting the spacing between bars in the bar chart.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve these in Vega-Lite?
Here is the code, I worte:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"X":1,"Y":1,"KPI Name": "KPI 1", "Target Value": 50, "Current Value": 30, "Base line": 10, "Base line text": "Baseline Value: 10", "Historical Text": "24% Since Jun", "Updated Date": "Update 23 Jul 2024","Trend": "Increase"},
      {"X":2,"Y":1,"KPI Name": "KPI 2", "Target Value": 50, "Current Value": 30, "Base line": 10, "Base line text": "Baseline Value: 10", "Historical Text": "24%  Since Jun", "Updated Date": "Update 23 Jul 2024","Trend": "Increase"},
      {"X":3,"Y":1,"KPI Name": "KPI 3", "Target Value": 5000000, "Current Value": 3000000, "Base line": 1000000, "Base line text": "Baseline Value: 1000000", "Historical Text": "24%  Since Jun", "Updated Date": "Update 23 Jul 2024","Trend": "Increase"},
      {"X":1,"Y":2,"KPI Name": "KPI 4", "Target Value": 0.9, "Current Value": 0.6, "Base line": 0.2, "Base line text": "Baseline Value: 10%", "Historical Text": "24%  Since Jun", "Updated Date": "Update 23 Jul 2024","Trend": "Increase"}
    ]
  },
    "transform": [
    {"fold": ["Current Value", "Target Value"], "as": ["Measure", "Value"]},
    {"calculate": "min(datum['Target Value'],datum['Current Value'],0)", "as": "start_value"},
    {"calculate": "max(datum['Target Value'],datum['Current Value'])", "as": "max_value"},
    {"calculate": "datum.max_value+(0.27*datum.max_value)","as": "end_value"}
  ],
"facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "Y",
      "header":null
    },
    "column": {
      "field": "X",
      "header":null
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "width": 393,
    "height": 219,
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"nice": false},
      "title": null,
      "axis": null
    }
    },
    "layer":[
      {
        "mark": {
          "type": "rect",
          "width": 393,
          "height": 219,
          "fill": "#ffffff",
          "stroke": "#000000",
          "strokeWidth": 1,
          "cornerRadius": 4
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"value": 0, "axis": null},
          "y": {"value": 0, "axis": null}
        }
      },

      {
    "mark": {
      "type": "bar",
      "size": 19,
      "yOffset":-40,
      "xOffset":-40
    },
    "encoding": {
      "y": {
        "field": "Measure",
        "type": "ordinal",
      "sort":["Target Value","Current Value"],
      "title":null
      },
      "x": {
        "field": "Value",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": null,
        "axis": null,
        "scale":{"domain": ["start_value","end_value"]}
      },
      "color": {
        "field": "Measure",
        "type": "nominal",
        "title": null,
        "legend":null
      }
    }
  }
    ]

  },
  "resolve": {
    "axis": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"},
    "scale": {
      "x": "independent"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "facet": {
      "spacing": 48
    }
  }
}

I am intending to achieve the result as in the attached image.
output

This answer may help you get started:
Vega lite KPI Card with target line and conditional text
You just need to add several layers and logic to your card.
You can then easily repeat the cards with a hconcat etc
